# RestClient update database

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest, sql-update

here is my problem, I have this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if ( v == reserver ) {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",""+dateDepl));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("places",""+placesDepl));

        try {
            RestClient.doPost("/reserve.php", nameValuePairs, new OnResultListener() {                  
                @Override
                public void onResult(String json) {
                    if ( json.equals("update_ok")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Reserver.this, "Votre réservation a été enregistrée, merci.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

it is supposed to send date and places with RestClient to the script reserve.php :

```
<?php
 //-> Récupération des variables POST ou sortie en cas d'absence
 $laDate = $_POST['date'];
 $nbPlaces = $_POST['places'];

 //-> Recherche du mois
 $posFirstTiret = stripos($laDate, '-');
 $posLastTiret = strrpos($laDate, '-');
 $longueur = $posLastTiret-$posFirstTiret;
 $mois = substr($laDate, $posFirstTiret+1,$longueur);
 $leMois;

 switch ( $mois ) {
     case 1: $leMois="janvier";
             break;
     case 2: $leMois="fevrier";
             break;
     case 3: $leMois="mars";
             break;
     case 4: $leMois="avril";
             break;
     case 5: $leMois="mai";
             break;
     case 6: $leMois="juin";
             break;
     case 7: $leMois="juillet";
             break;
     case 8: $leMois="aout";
             break;
     case 9: $leMois="septembre";
             break;
     case 10: $leMois="octobre";
             break;
     case 11: $leMois="novembre";
             break;
     case 12: $leMois="decembre";
             break;
  }

 //-> Récupération du modèle SQL 
 require_once "../model/db.php";
 $mysqli = $sql->getConnection(); 

 //-> Recherche de la date dans la table des utilisateurs
 $requete = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$leMois."'";
 $resultat = operation( $mysqli, $requete );
 $nb = $resultat->num_rows;

 if ( $nb == 0 ) {
   // Table du mois non existante
  echo "Aucune proposition pour ce mois-ci!";
 }

 //-> Mise à jour du nombre de places dans la base de données
 $requete = "UPDATE".$leMois." SET places=places-".$nbPlaces." WHERE id LIKE '".$laDate."';";
 echo $requete;
 $resultat = lectureOne( $mysqli, $requete, 0 );

  if ( !$resultat ) {
   echo "La réservation a échoué.";
  } else {
     echo "update_ok";
   }
 }  

 ?>
```

but when I press the button, nothing happens at all.

I tried to echo the request, but it doesn't show me anything, I don't know where the problem is.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No, I don't get anything, I press the button and really nothing append, no toast, anything. Just errors about the SoundPool in LogCat, like Effect_Tick.ogg

Comment: Have you tried to call our rest api via the androids browser? Do you get any output then? You have to chnage $_POST to $_REQUEST in your php though

Comment: so open your browser on the device and type in http://yourdomain.com/reserve.php?date=120401&places=APLACE

Comment: It don't change anything with $_REQUEST

Comment: have you tried to open it in a browser like i said?

Comment: and put this line in first line of your php code `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I got : Notice: Undefined variable: leMois in /home/nsoliveau/public_html/Stifco/core/library/reserve.php on line 55
UPDATE SET places=places-APLACE WHERE id LIKE '120401';lectureOne :

Comment: so you see what your problem is

Comment: But, my variable is good, I think :/

Comment: no it isn't because think about if `switch ( $mois )`  $mois is 0 or 15 so your variable `$leMois;` is not initialised